# How to know if a background job is finished?

Tags: process, background-process, nohup

I invoke a script (do_something) in background via another script (do_manythings) as below.

```
nohup do_something &
```

How would I know in the parent script (do_manythings) that the job invoked (do_something) has been done?

Comment: You can use 'jobs' command to see the status of the process.. it will show the process ID and the current status..

Answer (score 12, accepted):

If you want to fire off a background job, do some other stuff, then stop and wait for the background job to finish, you can do

```
nohup do_something &
pid=$!
...more stuff...
wait $pid
```

Alternatively, you can test for the job having exited like this:

```
nohup do_something &
pid=$!
...more stuff...
ps -p $pid > /dev/null
[ $? == 1 ] && echo "it's gone, buddy!"
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also look for `start-stop-daemon` (examples in `/etc/init.d/`) if you want to use `do_something` as a daemon.

Answer (score 0):

You could check

```
ps -ef | grep 'do_something
```

If the result shows up, your script is still running.

you could also run

```
ps -ef | grep 'your_user_name'
```

to check all active running jobs on your ID.